# In Unity, Image to show icon works on one scene but not the other

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to show an icon on the UI when the player is looking at an enemy. The raycasting code, etc all works, but on one scene, the icon shows successfully, the other, it doesn't. I have tried copying, recreating, using different Sprites, none of it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CursorAffordance : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Sprite _combatAffordance;


    private CameraRaycaster _raycaster;

    private Image _image;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        _raycaster = FindObjectOfType<CameraRaycaster>();
        _image = FindObjectOfType<Image>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            print(_raycaster.layerHit);
        }

        switch (_raycaster.layerHit)
        {
            case Layer.Enemy:
                _image.sprite = _combatAffordance;
                _image.enabled = true;
                break;
            default:
                _image.sprite = null;
                _image.enabled = false;
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

The only thing i can find from debugging is _combatAffordance is somehow null the second run through , and stays null from then on, although in inspetor it still shows my Target sprite.

Comment: Does this problem happen when you load a new scen from the previous or you just run this script in two seperate scenes in the editor ?

Comment: @UriPopov I run in the editor, two seperate scenes. And I have pointed the _combatAffordance to the correct sprite in both

Comment: Hmm. This is strange try removing the  [SerializeField] and making it public.

Comment: It seems after restarting my computer, it works now, which is extra confusing, my guess is my playing about had got the unity engine inside the  editor in a weird state.